# HTTP request to wikipedia to get the page for scanning in C#

Tags: c#, json, httprequest, webrequest, wikipedia-api

I have a c# exercise for which I need to use Wikipedia.
I need to import a wikipedia page with a GET request in c#,   and then use this page and analyze it. I need to get all the float numbers on the page and output them to a json format.
How can I import the entire page including the content menu and not just the paragraphs?

Comment: `await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research")` gets the whole HTML content of the page